# Why is Sphinx-doc wrapping numbered list items in <p> when I insert a figure?

Tags: python-sphinx

Why does the following rst produce list items that look like this: `<li>...</li>`

```
#. Place red radish in end of trumpet
#. Bring trumpet to mouth
#. Blow hard
```

, while the following produces: `<li><p>...</p></li>`

```
#. Place red radish in end of trumpet
#. Bring trumpet to mouth

   .. figure:: image6.png

#. Blow hard
```

?

It messes up the styling.